# How to import bookmarks from users web browsers using python?

Tags: python, linux, browser, xbel

I am working on an RSS Reader type program and I would like it to be able to 
automatically import RSS feeds from the users browser bookmarks. I assume different
browsers use different methods to store bookmarks. Is there any library out there just for this purpose?

I only need it to work on Linux so I don't care about Windows or Mac only browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at: [XBEL](http://pyxml.sourceforge.net/topics/xbel/)